# I'm struggling to send E-mail in Remote Server,But it's working in local,In Remote Server its Throwing 'AuthenticationFailedException'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

Here is my Configuration file.
At same time I enabled Less Secure App is True in Receiver side Email also.
I'm using 587 smpt.gmail.com port Because I'm using HTTP only not HTTPS. In Local server even the receiver mail has two-step verification also happily mail is sending, but coming to Remote Server I'm getting `AuthenticationFailedException`. I tried so much code changes also, still I am not able to re-solve this one. I don't know where the problem is coming from.

**Config.xml**:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="abc@gmail.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emailSession" class="javax.mail.Session" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.user">abc@gmail.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">587</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean id="emailAuthenticator" class="com.user.service.EmailSMTPAuthenticator">
            <property name="username" value="abc@gmail.com"></property>
            <property name="password" value="xxxxxx"></property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"></property>
    <property name="session" ref="emailSession"></property>
</bean>
```

**EmailService**:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    private  JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendEmail(String from,String to,String subject,String message){
        try {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage=mailSender.createMimeMessage(); 
            mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");   
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the [debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Answer (score 0):

Authorization code is not  password

```java
<bean id="emailAuthenticator" class="com.user.service.EmailSMTPAuthenticator">
    <property name="password" value="{Authorization code}"></property>
</bean>
```